# UIImageView animation after action?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

I have a problem setting up an animation. The first imageview starts animating and when playsound1 is called then starts the second animation. Everything works fine but right now when the second animation stops there is no animation going on. So what I want to do is after the second animation stops  - the first to start all over-- then again when method is called to play the second animation . Any hints?

Here you can see  a part of the code as it is right now:

```
- (void)loadtest1 {
    NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test2.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test3.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test4.png"],
                           nil];

    test1.animationImages = imageArray;
    test1.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    test1.animationDuration = 1;

    [imageArray release];
    [test1 startAnimating];
}

- (void)loadtest2 {
    NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test4.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test5.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test6.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test7.png"],
                           nil];

    test2.animationImages = imageArray;
    test2.animationRepeatCount = -1;
    test2.animationDuration = 1;

    [imageArray release];
    [test2 startAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)playsound1 {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
    test1.hidden = 0;
    test2.hidden = 1;
    [test1 startAnimating];
    test2.center = test1.center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are trying to do is re-starting your first animation when the second one finishes

The correct way to handle this is through a [`CABasicAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), which allows you to specify a delegate whose `– animationDidStop:finished:` method is called when the animation is done.

If you do not want this way, a sort of workaround is the following: in `loadtest2`, after you start the animation, schedule a method for execution with a delay:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(loadTest1) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

this will (more or less) work satisfactorily because you know how long your animation will last. So, when the animation should be ended, `loadTest1` is executed and the first animation starts again.

Comment: I've tried and this way: [self performSelector:@selector(loadTest1) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
and it's not working. I should prolly try the other way and see what can i get. Thanks a lot.

Comment: would you put an NSLog statement in `loadTest1` to check that it is called when the second animation ends?

Comment: It works now. I've made another method for the imageview only without the sound and it works just fine, thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: I am glad that you got it working. I did not understand if the tip was useful for getting this right, if so, consider choosing this answer according to S.O. practices...